# How to install Qt5 designer and Qt5 packages in a python IDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt5

I have a problem using Qt5 designer on Ubuntu.

I managed to install Qt5 designer. I can create a GUI then save it in .ui format and convert it to .py format.
The problem comes after when I try to open the .py file in a python IDE (I tried Thonny, pyCharm and Anaconda). I have this error message:

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Process ended with exit code -6.

I tried several codes :

QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=path/to/plugins ./my_qt_app

pip uninstall PyQt5

pip install PyQt5

sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake

Comment: Sorry but your question is confusing. Qt Designer has nothing to do with PyQt5, so, having it installed or not should make no difference. Also, all the IDEs you listed require specific configuration in order to use modules (whether they already exist or they are to be installed), and it's unclear how you are actually doing that or from where.